# Constraints not update swift

Tags: swift, swift2, constraints

[image]

Hello,
I am having trouble with constraints and was hoping for a little guidance.

In the image attached.

1 = What I start out with. The red section is a table view, the blue is a button.

2 = What is happening.

3 = What I want to happen.

I have an autolayout constraint from blue to red. But sometimes the red section hides a section in it and gets smaller, but the blue area does not follow when this occurs.

Im just curious if I need to programmatically set another constraint on the blue area. OR like refresh the constraint somehow so it knows to move up to the red area.

Comment: It's difficult for us to help you if we can't see your code.

Comment: Just looking for some guidance here. Wouldn't think you need to see code. I just have a button with a constraint 10 away from the tableview. Table view gets smaller and bigger, but button does not follow.

Comment: From your question it's unclear if you actually resize the table view or if you only remove a section / some rows. As Mike points out in his answer a table view's height won't adjust to the height of it's contents because otherwise it would totally exceed the height of the screen in most cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UITableView isn't actually getting smaller or larger. Even if it doesn't have a lot of content inside of it, the frame stays the same.

If you want the behavior in 3, you could put the button in it's own cell in the table. Then it would always be at the bottom of the rest of your cells.